# Python selenium result of submitting a form

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently I am testing my flask app using selenium. So I have an html with simple FlaskForm in it which contains submit button. Of course I can click on it and submit a form using

```
    btn = driver.find_element_by_id("submit-btn").click()
```

But the problem is that `click` method doesn't return anything.

So my question is how can I get at least the response code of submitted form so I can be sure that my tests run ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `click()` does not return anything, and you cannot get `response code` by selenium as well.

You need to verify test based on what the web displays, like success alert, text or something.